In Nuxt3, the text content is rendered but the click functionality is not working after deployment (works locally)
This is a simple VUE3 template that I have, but @click functionality doesn't work in index.html file that's generated from npm run generate. Therefore, it's not working after it's deployed as well.
<template>
   <div>
       Pages/Index.vue
       <p>Test latest update</p>
       <Button label="Test" @click="test()" icon="pi pi-check" />
       <button onclick="alert('I work')">Test Again</button>
    </div>
</template>


I don't have anything special in the nuxtConfig and package.json.
I tried running the dist folder that's generated from npm run generate with serve dist and that seemed to work.

Where and how do you deploy your app? Give a try to Netlify. Any errors in the console?
